# getting error as no such variable

Tags: tcl

I want to indent all the codes of a file where all the lines are starting from extreme left. so I wrote the code.

```
set fp [open without_spaces.tcl]
set new_file [open final.tcl w+]
set start 0
while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} {
    puts $line
    if {[regexp {\{$} $line]} {
        puts $new_file $nline
        incr $start
        #Now start brace is here, lets find closing brace
        continue
    } elseif {[regexp {\}$} $line]} {
        puts $new_file $nline
        incr $start -1
        continue
    }
    if {$start > 0} {
        puts $new_file "\t\t\t\t" $nline
    }
    if {[regexp {^\#} $line]} {}
        continue
    }
close $fp
close $new_file
```

But this gives me error ***can't read "nline": no such variable*** and removing the ***nline*** gives me an empty output file.
Please help me out.

PS- I know this is a silly question. [still a NOOB]

Comment: Where the variable `nline`  defined ? You should do the increment to the variable, not to the value. Instead of `incr $start`, it should be `incr start`

Comment: Changing it to incr start and $nline to $line, I'm still unable to indent the code. the final.tcl is exactly the same as without_spaces.tcl .
what could be done now? @Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `$nline` to `$line`

this will produce output on `final.tcl`. I have tested it.